# Displaying Custom Type content one field at a time

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've been trying to get my head around this but is it possible to display content from a Custom Type (Drupal 7) one field at a time? Right now, typing `<?php render($page['content']); ?>` just displays all the content all in one go (in the order of the fields it was written in). Being able to display it one field at a time can allow for some complex layout styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the individual fields when the *node* is rendered (as opposed to the *page*). By default, [`node.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php) is used for that.